# How to make a reference superficial

Tags: c#

I am wondering how one would force one variable to always point to what another variable is pointing to.

Considering the following program :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person p = new Person{Name = "Aelphaeis", Age = -1};
        p.introBehavior.Introduce();
    }

    class Person
    {
        public String Name { get;set; }
        public Int32 Age { get;set; }

        public IIntroductionBehavior introBehavior{get;set;}

        public Person(){
            Name = "over";
            Age = 9000;

            introBehavior = new IntroductionBehavior(Name, Age);
        }
    }

    class IntroductionBehavior : IIntroductionBehavior
    {
        String Name;
        Int32 Age;

        public IntroductionBehavior(string  name, int age){
            Age = age;
            Name = name;
        }

        public void Introduce(){
            Console.WriteLine("I'm " + Name + " and I am " + Age + " years old");
        }

    }

    interface IIntroductionBehavior
    {
        void Introduce();
    }   
}
```

If you run this program you will get

> I'm over and I am 9000 years old

The desired behavior would be for the Name and Age inside of the IntroductionBehavior to point to whatever the value of the properties inside of Person are pointing too. It should print :

> I'm Aelphaeis and I am -1 years old

If this is not possible what type of redesign would could I implement to ensure that IntroductionBehavior will always print the values of Person without making IntroductionBehavior aware of Person?

Edit: A lot of people seem to be confused about why I don't want to make IntroductionBehavior Aware of Person.

Introduction is actually intended to do an operation on a repository. The variables name and age represent the repository which will be manipulated. I'm trying to loosely couple things so that they are easy to debug.

Comment: Why just you don't reference Person in your IIntroductionBehavior?

Comment: @Ksven While it doesn't seem sensible here, I'd like to test the interface using test cases and it should be able to function independently of Person.

Comment: Seems like a very convoluted way of doing things to me. Why don't you just point the `Console.WriteLine` stuff with a `delegate` instead of creating a separate class implementing an interface?

Comment: You could create a new behaviour every time you need it, or you could create a new interface for `Person` to inherit from. I'm not sure that either would be particularly valuable, though - why don't you want to reference `Person` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `IntroductionBehavior` reference to person:

```
class IntroductionBehavior : IIntroductionBehavior
{
    private Person person;

    public IntroductionBehavior(Person person){
        this.person = person;
    }

    public void Introduce(){ 
        Console.WriteLine("I'm {0} and I am {1} years old", 
           person.Name, person.Age); // NOTE: use string format
    }
}

class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }

    public IIntroductionBehavior introBehavior { get; set; }

    public Person(){
        Name = "over";
        Age = 9000;
        introBehavior = new IntroductionBehavior(this);
    }
}
```

Thus `IntroductionBehavior` will get name and age values or person at time when you'll ask it to introduce.

Another option is creating `IntroductionBehavior` instance in property getter instead of creating it in constructor:

```
  public IIntroductionBehavior introBehavior
  {
     get { return new IntroductionBehavior(Name, Age); }
  }
```

Thus `IntroductionBehavior` will capture name and age values of person at time when you get it instead of time of person creation. NOTE: if you'll update person's name or age between getting `introBehavior` and introducing it, then you will see old data.

Of course, usage of `IntroductionBehavior` class is arguable..

Comment: I'm kind of liking this suggestion. I hadn't thought of overloading the constructor to allow for this. I'm going to sit on it for a couple minutes and think about it.

Comment: @Aelphaeis in first case `IntroductionBehavior` acts like a command object - it encapsulates receiver (person) and can be invoked later by calling `Introduce()`

Comment: Ultimately, I did not go with this approach; however, this approach has provoked me to think enough to come to a conclusion and I think that it is the most useful for this purpose so I've marked this as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Usually what you then do in C# is pass the parent of the object to its constructor. In this case `IntroductionBehavior` would store the parent `Person`.

For example:

```
class IntroductionBehavior : ...
{
   public Person Parent {get; private set;}

   public IntroductionBehavior(Person parent)
   {
        Parent = parent;
   }

   ...
}
```

Then you can use `Parent.Age` to get the age.

Answer (score 2):

Three thoughts:

**1) Why have a separate class `IntroductionBehavior` when you could just do:**

```
class Person : IIntroductionBehavior
{
    public String Name { get;set; }
    public Int32 Age { get;set; }

    public Person(){
        Name = "over";
        Age = 9000;
    }

    public void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm " + Name + " and I am " + Age + " years old");
    }
}
```

**2) You could implement the property getters/setters to modify the behavior**

```
public String Name
{
    get { return introBehavior.Name; }
    set { introBehavior.Name = value; }
}

public Int32 Age
{
    get { return introBehavior.Age; }
    set { introBehavior.Age = value; }
}
```

**3) You could encapsulate the entire behavior, too**
This could be in combination with 2), so instead of defining the property `introductionBehavior` as settable, you could do this:

```
private IntroductionBehavior introBehavior;

public Person()
{
    introBehavior = new IntroductionBehavior() { Name = "Test", Age = 123 };
}

public IIntroductionBehavior introductionBehavior
{
    get { return introBehavior; }
}

public String Name
{
    get { return introBehavior.Name; }
    set { introBehavior.Name = value; }
}

public Int32 Age
{
    get { return introBehavior.Age; }
    set { introBehavior.Age = value; }
}
```

Combine 2) and 3) to store name and age in the behavior only instead of duplicating the information (2 properties in `Person`,  two properties in `introductionBehavior`).

I find it rather questionable that the `introductionBehavior` should be settable from outside the `Person` class. That's why I think 3) is a good approach. You say in comments to the question that all this is about automatic testing of the interface independently of the `Person` class. In my opinion the combination of 2) and 3) allows you to do exactly that with the added benefit that parts of testing `Person` are done by testing `IntroductionBehavior` already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following helper template `SharedValue<T>` to create references to values (i.e. add another level of indirection). 
This allows you to share the values. You have to add `.Value` to the variables if you want to access the "real" value, otherwise you just get the "pointer".
This is comparable to a `shared_ptr` (or any other pointer like constructs) in `C++`.

```
class SharedValue<T>
{
    T   Value; // stores a single value
}
```

Your code would then look like this:

```
class Person
{
    private readonly SharedValue<string> name = new SharedValue<string>();
    private readonly SharedValue<Int32> age = new SharedValue<Int32>();

    public String Name { get {return name.Value;} set {name.Value = value;} }
    public Int32 Age { get {return age.Value;} set {age.Value = value;} }

    public IIntroductionBehavior introBehavior{get;set;}

    public Person(){
        Name = "over";
        Age = 9000;

        introBehavior = new IntroductionBehavior(name, age); // note that we pass the SharedValues
    }
}

class IntroductionBehavior : IIntroductionBehavior
{
    SharedValue<String> Name;
    SharedValue<Int32> Age;

    public IntroductionBehavior(SharedValue<string>  name, SharedValue<int> age){
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Introduce(){
        Console.WriteLine("I'm " + Name.Value + " and I am " + Age.Value + " years old");
    }

}
```

**If this results in a good overall design is a totally different question!**

Comment: It is certainly an interesting thought, +1 for the thought. Definitely the most creative solution